# Drush install on RedHat 6 seems to do nothing

Tags: drush, installation

I'm trying to get drush installed on a RHEL6 server. I've done the install via pear and also by unpacking the tar ball to /usr/local/share. Both methods result in the same result: typing "drush" from any location does nothing. To be more specific it hangs without any errors that I can see.

It doesn't give any error about not finding it in the path, it just hangs.

I have had it working on other RHEL6 machines, but I haven't been able to pin down any differences between the installs to give me an idea what's wrong with this one.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use the package manager:

```
yum -y install php-drush-drush
```

Alternatively, if it's installed in `/usr/local/share` then make a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/drush/drush /usr/local/bin/drush
```

Then, verify it works with:

```
which drush
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It raises a couple of questions. Yum install raises a couple complaints. 1. It says I need php-posix, but yum can't find any instance of php-posix. 2. It seems to think that php-devel-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64 needs to be replaced with php = 5.3.3-14.el6_3. Same for mbstring and pspell. Will it really not work with the .x86_64 versions?

Comment: posix support can be added with php-process. Drush will work with 64-bit versions of your server libraries; it's a PHP software library, so as long as PHP works, Drush will work. Drush 5 requires PHP 5.2.0 or higher, and Drush 6+ requires PHP 5.3.3 or higher.

Comment: The version of Drush provided by package managers are typically outdated - or very outdated. And recent versions of Drush should be installed in a manner that makes it impossible to install using the OS package manager.

Comment: True, but it was relatively up-to-date in 2013 when the comment was posted :-)

Answer (score 0):

The commands below have been tested successfully on Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS, RedHat and other linux systems.

1. `sudo wget --quiet -O - http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drush-7.x-5.6.tar.gz | sudo tar -zxf - -C /usr/local/share`
2. `sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/drush/drush /usr/local/bin/drush`
3. `drush`

The last line drush is command. If it displays a list of drush command, it means drush was installed successfully!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Drush Luncher](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher)

it can be easily installed on each linux distributes by :

```
wget -O drush.phar https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher/releases/download/0.6.0/drush.phar

chmod +x drush.phar
sudo mv drush.phar /usr/bin/drush
```

**old method, with using `yum`**

```
sudo yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-$(rpm -E '%{rhel}').noarch.rpm
```

then

```
sudo yum install drush
```